# How to extract the oldest value for a column from a set of rows instead of all the rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the following format

```
Name|Token|   Date  |
---------------------
John|7    |2010-4-30|
John|7    |2011-4-30|
John|9    |2011-5-30|
John|9    |2012-7-30|
John|9    |2015-1-30|
John|7    |2016-10-1|
John|9    |2016-11-3|
John|9    |2018-1-1 |
John|7    |2021-9-9 |
```

I am trying to copy data from this table to a new table and I need to find out the oldest date from the latest set of rows that have the token 9 for every person. Like in this case, I need to get `2016-11-3` as my output. Now for the cases where all token's are 9 I can easily use the `group by` clause and `min(date)` and get my result, but in cases like this if I use the `group by` clause and `min(date)` I would get results like `john|9|2011-5-30|` but it is not correct because the token `7` breaks the set on `2016-10-1`.

Additional cases
Case 1:

```
Name|Token|   Date  |
---------------------
John|7    |2010-4-30|
John|7    |2011-4-30|
John|9    |2011-5-30|
John|9    |2012-7-30|
```

Answer => 2011-5-30. because row no 3 and 4, both have token 9 and are right after each other hence the sequence

```
John|9    |2011-5-30|
John|9    |2012-7-30|
```

Case 2:

```
Name|Token|   Date  |
---------------------
John|7    |2010-4-30|
John|7    |2011-4-30|
John|9    |2011-5-30|
John|9    |2012-7-30|
John|9    |2015-1-30|
John|7    |2016-10-1|
John|9    |2016-11-3|
John|9    |2018-1-1 |
John|7    |2021-9-9 |
John|9    |2022-1-1 |
```

Answer -> 2022-1-1, because the latest set of rows which have 9 as token and are right after each other (in this case only 1 row) is

```
John|9    |2022-1-1 |
```

Case 3:

```
    Name|Token|   Date  |
    ---------------------
    John|9    |2010-4-30|
    John|9    |2011-4-30|
    John|9    |2011-5-30|
    John|9    |2012-7-30|
    John|9    |2015-1-30|
    John|9    |2016-10-1|
    John|9    |2016-11-3|
    John|9    |2018-1-1 |
    John|7    |2021-9-9 |
```

Answer ->2010-4-30, here the latest set of rows with token 9 which are in a sequence are

```
    John|9    |2010-4-30|
    John|9    |2011-4-30|
    John|9    |2011-5-30|
    John|9    |2012-7-30|
    John|9    |2015-1-30|
    John|9    |2016-10-1|
    John|9    |2016-11-3|
    John|9    |2018-1-1 |
```

Comment: "...from the latest set of rows..." -- How do you define the **latest**? Remember that in relational databases tables rows do not have inherent ordering.

Comment: Token `7` does not break the set, since the rows don't have ordering. Voting to close since the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I'm trying to say. If you see, the dates are in ascending order from 2010-4-30 to 2021-9-9. so the latest set of rows with the token 9 would be row no 7 and 8 and the answer would be 2016-11-3 because from the latest set of rows (set of rows as in the rows which have token 9) which have the token 9, 2016-11-3 is the oldest date. For my use case, I need to find out the oldest date where the token was 9 for the set of rows which have 9 as token. @TheImpaler

Comment: Ah... I didn't see that ordering before. My bad. Let me see what I can do...

Answer (score 1):

This is a Gaps & Islands problem with a twist. You can do:

```
with
g as (
  select *,
    sum(inc) over(partition by name order by date) as grp
  from (
    select *,
      case when token <> lag(token) over(partition by name order by date) 
      then 1 else 0 end as inc
    from t
  ) x
)
select g.name, min(g.date) as min_date
from g
join (
  select name, max(grp) as max_grp from g where token = 9 group by name
) m on m.name = g.name and m.max_grp = g.grp
group by g.name
```

Result (with modified data for testing purposes):

```
 name   min_date   
 ------ ---------- 
 Alice  2019-03-01 
 John   2016-11-03
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02e5dfd3d93718419ad7d0ca28b52f48).